# Avoid redefining a perl format in an eval

Tags: perl

I've got a subroutine that delares a [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) in an `eval` expression. If this subroutine gets called more than once, perl warns that a format has been redefined.

This code:

```
use warnings;
routine();
routine();

sub routine{
    my $s = "FAIL";
    my $def = "format =\n@<<<<@>>>>\n\$s, \$s\n.";
    eval $def;
    write;
}
```

prints

```
FAIL  FAIL
Format STDOUT redefined at (eval 2) line 1.
FAIL  FAIL
```

Is it possible to delete the format declaration at the end of the subroutine?

Comment: Have you considered using Perl6::Form? Must better. Avoids this problem completely.

Comment: I'm just trying to make a quick fix to an ancient module. I'm pretty sure the developer didn't expect this sub to be called more than one. Turns out that's wrong :)

Comment: I think the advice from `use diagnostics;` is the easiest fix. I'm still curious to know if the format can be removed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that uses a flag to avoid redefining the format.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

routine();
routine();

my $format_defined;

sub routine{
    my $s = "FAIL";
    if (!$format_defined) {
        my $def = "format =\n@<<<<@>>>>\n\$s, \$s\n.";
        eval $def;
        $format_defined = 1;
    }
    write;
}
```

Here is a more sophisticated solution that allows for the format to be redefined for each call. It uses a temporary filehandle in place of STDOUT that redirects the output to a scalar, which you can then print to STDOUT.

```
routine('FAIL');
routine('PASS');

sub routine{
    my $s = shift;

    format REPORT =
@<<<<@>>>>
$s,  $s
.
    my $report;
    open my $fh, '>', \$report;
    select $fh;
    $~ = 'REPORT';
    write;
    close $fh;

    select STDOUT;
    print $report;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten years after I faced the same problem and realized it's not so easy to get the formats working flexibly enough. Solutions mentioned by @stevenl were not so effective, because limiting eval to only first occurence, results repeating format with first time eval'ed variable. So I've had nice table fulfilled with the same datas of first record. Second solution doesn't implement eval, so format definition cannot be built dynamically.

The workaround i have applied was just:

```
no warnings qw/redefine/;
```

inside the body of subroutine.
Yes, I know, ugly but effective. Still searching for a better solution :)